# Make openssl RSA algorithm deterministic

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, emscripten

I am trying to compile a program using openssl with emscripten but it is returning bogus keys. I would like the key that RSA_generate_key() returns to be the same every time, when given the same seed, so I can test what might be going wrong.

I have tried replacing RAND_poll with my own implementation that always adds the same numbers to the pool and have defined `GETPID_IS_MEANINGLESS`.

What else do I need to remove/disable/replace?

Testcase appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to test other parts of my program so I would like the key that `RSA_generate_key()` returns to be the same every time, when given the same seed.

Simply call `RSA_generate_key()` once, and dump the result to a text file. Then, create temporary constants and hard code the keys and result from calling `RSA_generate_key()` and replace all calls to `RSA_generate_key()` with the hardcoded constants.

Furthermore, when you are done simply uncomment the calls to `RSA_generate_key()` and comment out all of the constants.

**Alternatively,** "define a wrapper around the RSA key generation and return constant values. Then you have only one code location that needs fixing later." - Duncan Jones.

Comment: Or... define a wrapper around RSA key generation and return constant values. Then you have only one code location that needs fixing later.

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified in my question that I am trying to compile openssl with emscripten and want to generate a deterministic key so I can try and work out what stage the program/compilation is going wrong.